# How to interpolate column-wise in Simulink with a matrix as source

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a m x n matrix which I want to use as a source in Simulink. The output of the source should be a column of size n. The data needs to be interpolated between columns.

Example:

Source matrix:

```
[ 2  4  8;
  3  6  9;
  5 10 15 ]
```

Output of simulink model at different times for this example matrix:

```
t = 0 :         t = 0.5 : (interpolated)        t = 1 :
[ 2;            [ 3.0;                          [  4;
  3;              4.5;                             6;
  5 ]             7.5 ]                           10 ]
```

The example shows only outputs for t = [0, 0.5, 1.0], but the actual source needs to be continuous.

I tried the `direct lookup table (n-D)`, but this block doesn't interpolate between columns. I tried to use the `Interpolation Using Prelookup` block in combination with the `Prelookup` block, but I don't understand how to use these blocks.